# save console output of each run of a for loop in separate files

Tags: r, sink

I want to save console output of each run of a for loop in a separate text file. I am doing the following.

```
for(i in 1:x)
{
  sink(paste0("file", i, ".txt"))

  ## do something

}
```

But with this after sometime I am getting an error

```
Error in sink() : sink stack is full
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you have to close the connection to the file per `sink()`, so:

```
for(i in 1:x) {
  sink(paste0("file", i, ".txt"))
  ## do something
  sink()
}
```